# Update State from Fetched API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data from two separate APIs and updating their states individually. Afterwards, I'm mapping through the nba data and looping through the animeData object to update the allData state that will consist of an array of objects. The final output should be something like this
[
{
"PHI": "Natsume Yuujinchou"
},
{
"LAL": "Natsume Yuujinchou"
},
{
"MIN": "Natsume Yuujinchou"
}]. Lastly, I will render this information but I can't seem to update the allData state as it gives me the infinite rerender loop. Is there any way to fix this?

```
const [nbaData, setNbaData] = useState(null)
const [animeData, setAnimeData] = useState(null)
const [allData, setAllData] = useState(null)

const getData = async () => {
    const nbaone = await fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/games? 
    start_date=2023-03-10}&end_date=2023-03-10`)
    const nbaData = await nbaone.json()
        if(nbaData !== null){
            setNbaData(nbaData.data)
        }
        const anime = await fetch(`https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random`)
        const animechan = await anime.json()
        if(animechan !== null){
            setAnimeData(animechan)
        }
    
}

if(nbaData !== null && animeData !== null){
    setAllData(() => {
        nbaData.map(item => {
            for(let key in animeData){
                return {
                    [item.home_team.abbreviation]: animeData[key]
                }
            }
        })
    })
}



useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [])
```

Comment: You have to return something in `setAllData(() => {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the 'if' logic inside an `useEffect`, otherwise you'll be setting the state up once again on every render, causing the infinite loop:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (nbaData && animeData) {
    const newData = nbaData.map((item) => ({
      [item.home_team.abbreviation]: animeData.anime,
    }));
    setAllData(newData);
  }
}, [nbaData, animeData]);
```